# Solr facet offset by term/prefix rather than index

Tags: solr

I'm generating facet counts for a **multivalued** field and sorting them by `index` in order to see them in alphabetical order. Given a particular facet prefix, I would like to jump to its place in the facet count list and show the facet counts surrounding it. For example, if my prefix is "wha" then I would want the following returned (four before and four after):

```
weld 1
welsh 5
west 4
wetland 1
whale 99
wheat 123
wheel  1
whey 9
```

There are millions of values in the field and so I can't just ask for them all. I need to be able to jump to that location or use some kind of filter on the facet counts themselves. I've tried using `facet.offset`, but I have to basically do a binary search in order to find the appropriate offset which is too slow.

I could probably get close enough if I could put in a range for a facet prefix. For example `facet.prefix=[we TO wk]` or even multiple prefixes like `facet.prefix=we,wf,wg,wh,wi,wj,wk`.

I'm currently using other non-Solr solutions to accomplish this, but I would like to use **Solr 6.6** in order to take advantage of filter queries.

Comment: Using Solr 6.6.0